# Configuration of user tools visual studio 2015 vsDiffMerge.exe arguments

Tags: visual-studio-2015, merge, configuration, arguments, compare

I was able to find the vsDiffMerge.exe here :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe

I am unable to find the default arguments for compare and merge operations.

Can someone help me ?

I don't want to reset my Visual Studio to recover the arguments.

Edit :
The merge default arguments' are %1 %2 %3 %4 %6 %7 /m /t

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recover from my problem by deleting all entries in configure user tools window.